# Bad_ACCESS error i dont quite understand

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i get a bad_access error when i try to run my program, normally i can figure this stuff out but when i get the error it jumps me to this line of code.

`int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);`

I did not write whats above, but when i remove the following program runs fine...

```
NSLog(@"Store Data Count : %i", [storedData count]);
if ([storedData count] < 4) {
```

It was working before, and storedData is an NSMutableDictionary. I dunno if thats enough info, but if anyone could let me know what going on that would be really awesome. Thanks!

Comment: storedData has likely been prematurely released. How is it being created, retained, and released in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you've messed up your memory management and either over-released an object or sent a message to an object that's been released. Turn on `NSZombieEnabled` and you'll probably find out where very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the `storeData` outside the method that you are using it, make sure your `storedData` is retained and not be released anywhere before you use it.